# ERROR Error getting download URL: [FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'Sermon/1705503121152' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)]

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a video with identifiers. So the goal is  to upload the videos to firebase storage whilst saving the identifiers to firestore, but i keep getting this error.

> ERROR  Error getting download URL: [FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'Sermon/1705503121152' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)]

heres my code

```
  async function handleUpload() {

    if (videoFile) {
      await upload(videoFile);
    } else {
      alert("Please select a video first.");
    }
  }

  async function upload(uri) {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
  
    const storageRef = ref(storage, "Sermon/" + new Date().getTime());
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);
  
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", (snapshot) => {
      // Handle upload progress if needed
      const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log(`Upload progress: ${progress}%`);
  
      if (snapshot.state === "paused") {
        console.log("Upload paused");
      } else if (snapshot.state === "running") {
        console.log("Upload running");
        if (progress === 100) {
          console.log("Upload completed");
          handleUploadSuccess(uploadTask);
        }
      } 
    });
  }
  
  async function handleUploadSuccess(uploadTask) {
    try {
      const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
      await saveRecord(
        downloadUrl,
        title,
        preacher,
        series,
        new Date().getTime()
      );
      setVideoFile("");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting download URL:", error);
    }
  }

  async function saveRecord(url, title, preacher,  series, createdAt) {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "sermon"), {
        url,
        title,
        preacher,
        series,
        createdAt,
        isFeatured: '0'
      });
      console.log("file saved", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code might be trying to get a download URL before the upload is complete.  The object doesn't exist in storage until the upload finishes.

Instead of using `snapshot.state === "running"` and `progress === 100` to determine completion, you should use the pattern shown in the example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress), which I have redacted here to make it more clear where completion is fully known:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 

  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }

);
```

Read the comments to see where successful upload is known - it's in the third callback function parameter to `on()`, which you are currently not using.

Also consider reviewing the API documentation for [UploadTask.on](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on) to better understand how it works.  Specifically:

> Events have three callback functions (referred to as next, error, and complete).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're calling `getDownloadURL` on a non-existing reference, or before the file upload has completed on the server.

I recommend simplifying the code and using the fact that `uploadTask` is a promise, so you can await it:

```
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob);

await uploadTask; // 

handleUploadSuccess(uploadTask);
```

I also typically don't use `uploadTask.snapshot.ref`, but use `storageRef` instead.